# RestConf in Cisco Device uri Keypath not found for /ip/prefix-lists/prefixes/name

Tags: cisco-ios, yang, ietf-restconf

I am trying to execute below restconf API Get Request and getting error "uri keypath not found". The Path is present in Yang module

```
https://<device-ip>/restconf/data/Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/ip/prefix-lists/prefixes/name

--- Response
{
    "ietf-restconf:errors": {
        "error": [
            {
                "error-type": "application",
                "error-tag": "invalid-value",
                "error-message": "uri keypath not found"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have got the answer or not. Anyways, the problem may be with "prefix-lists". In some YANG models, it is "prefix-list". It depends on the revision of Cisco-IOS-XE-ip.yang.